# Can I copy or upload a Google Colab notebook onto a AWS Sagemaker instance?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, amazon-sagemaker

Want to have a copy of my Google Colab python notebook in my AWS Sagemaker Jupyter notebook(newbie to AWS Sagemaker)

I tried selecting all cells in my Colab notebook and pasting in my sagemaker Jupyter notebook using copy paste icons and via cmd+C and cmd+V

Cannot copy paste all selected cells at once between Colab and Sagemaker Jupyter notebooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While doing the drudgery work of copy pasting each cell between the notebooks(my bad), I realized that we could just **download the notebook as .ipynb file on Colab** and **upload on the Sagemaker notebook instance using the `Upload button`**.[image]